# Difference between select by class name and select by css? c#

Tags: c#, css, selenium

What is the difference between the following piece of coded:

```
IWebElement oldElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".p-client_container"));
IWebElement oldElement = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("p-client_container"));
```

Which one is faster? Also, aren't both of these statements the same?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: If any is faster, I bet the `ClassName` is faster. CSS selector strings require more parsing than a plain class name. That said, the speed difference, if any, is probably miniscule to the point of being completely irrelevant in 99.9% of situations.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it is the other way please refer to the code

Comment: by.classname uses By.cssselector under the hood , of use cssselector directly then you don't need the extra procesing By.class does

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_By_ClassName.htm

both are exactly same , second one converts the class to .class notation under the hood

when ever you are in doubt goto hithub and search the source code.

you can get the source code of By class at :

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/dbd00caf7b8dddce075679453cce648a573a97d1/dotnet/src/webdriver/By.cs

**By css**

```
    public static By CssSelector(string cssSelectorToFind)
    {
        if (cssSelectorToFind == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cssSelectorToFind", "Cannot find elements when name CSS selector is null.");
        }

        By by = new By(CssSelectorMechanism, cssSelectorToFind);
        by.description = "By.CssSelector: " + cssSelectorToFind;
        return by;
    }
```

**By classname:**

```
public static By ClassName(string classNameToFind)
        {
            if (classNameToFind == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("classNameToFind", "Cannot find elements when the class name expression is null.");
            }

            string selector = "." + By.EscapeCssSelector(classNameToFind);
            if (selector.Contains(" "))
            {
                // Finding elements by class name with whitespace is not allowed.
                // However, converting the single class name to a valid CSS selector
                // by prepending a '.' may result in a still-valid, but incorrect
                // selector. Thus, we short-ciruit that behavior here.
                throw new InvalidSelectorException("Compound class names not allowed. Cannot have whitespace in class name. Use CSS selectors instead.");
            }

            By by = new By(CssSelectorMechanism, selector);
            by.description = "By.ClassName[Contains]: " + classNameToFind;
            return by;
        }
```

so both are same but by.class name will have additional line of coding so need more fraction of second.

Comment: Which one is faster?

Comment: both are same , second one concatenates '.' infront of the stribg you provides so that might take less than many fraction of a second but other than that no difference

Comment: Technically the one that doesn't convert: css selector.

Comment: @Codexer see the source code for reference

Comment: @PDHide to be honest, I don't care what the source looks like (I didn't ask what the routines did). I'm not seeing any kind of benchmarking, how can you say `might take less than many fraction of a second`, these are assumptions, there are tests that can be done to confirm this. You left no facts confirming which one is "faster".

Comment: @Codexer its common sense to know more line code more processing time , both uses CssSelectorMechanism if you check the source code

Comment: what bench mark will you do between same systems ?

Comment: its exactly the same thing CssSelectorMechanism difference being that second selenium does all parsing of changing space to '.' first one user have to change space to '.' to specify class

Comment: @Codexer `By(CssSelectorMechanism, cssSelectorToFind);`  this is the method cold in both the `By.methods` .

Comment: @Codexer and its weird to say that you don't care how source code looks like !  source code gives you exact idea how the implementation is